# Checkbox fires more than one event

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have a dynamic tab where I have checkboxes. I put an event `onCheckedChanged` on them. It works first time, but after postback, my tab is recreated and when I click on another checkbox, I get more than one event being triggered.

Here is the code to create the tab :

```
private void initCatalog()
        {
            foreach (Article art in listArticle)
            {
                TableRow ligne = new TableRow();
                ligne.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

                TableCell celluleITMREF = new TableCell();
                celluleITMREF.Width = Unit.Percentage(10);
                celluleITMREF.Text = art._ITMREF;

                TableCell celluleCBOX = new TableCell();
                celluleCBOX.Width = Unit.Percentage(8);

                CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox();
                cbox.ID = "cbox." + f._FOURNISSEUR + "." + art._ITMREF;
                cbox.Checked = hfArticlesPaniers.Value.Contains(cbox.ID);
                //cbox.Enabled = !(hfArticlesPaniers.Value.Contains(cbox.ID));
                cbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cbox_CheckedChanged);
                cbox.AutoPostBack = true;
                cbox.CssClass = "c";

                celluleCBOX.Controls.Add(cbox);
                ligne.Cells.Add(celluleITMREF);
                ligne.Cells.Add(celluleCBOX);

                tabArticle.Rows.Add(ligne);
            }
        }
```

Here is the event for the checkbox :

```
protected void cbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox c = sender as CheckBox;

            Response.Write("<script>alert(\"" + c.ID + "\");</script>");
        }
```

Here is the page_Load event :

```
protected void page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
       this.initCatalog();
}
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: One solution could be just checking IsPostback before adding the event listener. If its a postback then simply don't add any listener.

Comment: Yes, but when my tab is recreated, checkbox won't have the event and the event will never trigger.

Comment: why not simply use some **dataBindings** for *listArticle* and make use of a [dataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. I've a method who order the list after she was create ... I deleted the method and it worked.

I don't know why it made mistakes ...

```
private void orderCatalog()
        {
            var tab = from TableRow tr in tabArticle.Rows
                      orderby tr.Cells[1].Text
                      select tr;

            List<TableRow> l = new List<TableRow>();

            foreach (TableRow tr in tab)
            {
                l.Add(tr);
            }

            tabArticle.Rows.Clear();

            foreach (TableRow tr in l)
            {
                tabArticle.Rows.Add(tr);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of `art` in `listArticle` will cause the event handler to be added to the event by the line

```
  cbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cbox_CheckedChanged);
```

executing each time. (i.e. you're adding the handler multiple times)

In addition, each running of `initCatalog` will also cause this if the page is not destroyed and loaded again in between.

Move the above line to a place where it will only be executed once after the page loads.

**EDIT**

on re-reading your code, adding multiple times within the loop is probably what you intended as there are multiple checkboxes. But after the postback, the `initCatalog()` may be executed again, thereby adding the event once more?